# ngCordovaOauth plug-in in Ionic App not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, oauth, ionic-framework

I've passed a lot of time trying to make the [ngCordovaOauth](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/) plugin to work, but i keep getting the same error *"Could not find InAppBrowser plugin"*.

I've already installed the In-app-browser plugin, and i'm using ng-cordova but it doesn't work.

This is my controller

```
    .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaOauth) {

    $scope.login = function(){
        $cordovaOauth.facebook("MY_APP_ID", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });  
    }     
})
```

These are my installed plugins

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.2-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"
```

Any idea of what could i be doing wrong?, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are including the proper js files?

Comment: sometimes it helps to remove the platform (for example `ionic platform remove android`) and add it again, and install plugins again. Not claiming that it will definitely help, but it's worth trying if nothing else helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `ng-cordova.js` replace all the occurencies of `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` with `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

Comment: if it is doesn't work, make the same in ng-cordova.min.js